# URL Rewrite troubleshoot

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

We have our URL rewrite as followed. I tested the pattern in IIS 8.5 URL Rewrite and the patterns matched as what we wanted. However, it's 404 every single time. Will someone take a look and see what is wrong with my URL rewrite? Thank you.

URL: devbox.mysite.com/article/how-to-use-onedrive

Pattern: `(.*)/article/(.*)$`
Action Rewrite URL: `{R:1}/article/?artID={R:2}`

Currently the page shows 404. Below is the XML code in web.config file.

```
<rule name="Article-rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)/article/(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/article/?artID={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Can you add some more detail on what  you want to achieve and your exact rule XML. At the moment it looks like your destination URL is `devbox.mysite.com/article/?artID=how-to-use-onedrive` does that work when you browse to it?

Comment: Yes, if I browse to the URL devbox.mysite.com/article/?artID=how-to-use-onedrive on any browser, it works fine. But I want it to work when the user type in devbox.mysite.com/article/how-to-use-onedrive on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rule name="Article-rewrite" enabled="true"> 
    <match url="article/(.*)$" /> 
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" /> 
    <action type="Rewrite" url="article/?artID={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" /> 
</rule>
```

I've removed the domain from the match url, as you're not switching the domain.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the help. It works! However, can you tell me why my url rewrite is not working but yours is?

Comment: I _think_ its down to the match you had at the start not capturing the protocol (http/https), but that's just a guess - rewrite rules are a lot harder to test than redirect ones as the result is invisible.

Comment: Ive just some playing and I can't get it to rewrite anything other than relative links, which makes sense as its never going to leave your application with a rewrite.

Comment: Thanks again. I will sure try that next time if it does not work.